# "dir/*: No such file or directory" with find -exec ... "{}/*"

Tags: bash, macos, find

The current directory contains files and directories. The directories have no sub-directories, but may contain zero or more files, for example:

```
./file1
./file2
./directory1/file3
./directory2/file4
./directory2/file5
./directory3/
```

When I execute `find . -type d -maxdepth 1` I get a listing of the directories:

```
./directory1
./directory2
```

If I execute `mv ./directory1/* .` all files in directory1 are moved to the current level `.` so I thought I could use find -exec to do everything in one go:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec mv "{}/*" . \;
```

But I get this response:

```
mv: rename ./directory1/* to ./*: No such file or directory
```

How can I move all the files in subdirectories to the current level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globbing (replacing `foo/*` with `foo/dirA`, `foo/dirB`, etc) is performed *by the shell*, not by `mv`. `find -exec` doesn't start a shell unless you do so manually; for example:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
       -exec sh -c 'for dir; do mv -- "$dir"/* .; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: I get the bit in the shell command, but can you explain the mechanics of the underscore, braces and + please?  (I get that braces are the found directory placeholder, but how does that get into the shell command?)

Comment: The underscore is `$0`. The braces are substituted with names and become `$1` and onward -- which is to say, the array `"$@"`, which is what `for` iterates over by default. Putting the braces **inside** the shell command would be a serious security bug, because you'd be treating filenames as code; if someone made a file that contains `$(rm -rf ~)` as part of its name, you don't want that to be executed. (These are called "shell injection" bugs; they're a common class of vulnerability).

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Comment: BTW, some folks think they can do `-exec sh -c "name='{}'"` safely, because the single-quotes suppress `$()` expansion. However, `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` is *also* a valid piece of a UNIX filename, and the `'`s in the name end the literal quotes in the script text, so keeping data completely out-of-band from code really is called for.

Comment: ...oh, and I didn't answer your question about `-exec ... {} +`; that's an alternative to `exec ... {} \;` that puts as many names as possible on the command line for each invocation, so instead of starting one shell per file, you start one shell per batch of files. It's been POSIX-mandated since the mid-2000s, so it's not a GNU-only extension.

Comment: I am hitting a problem: at the execution-level directory I'm getting alerts like 'mv: ./filename1.txt and ./filename1.txt are identical' even though the find command is only returning directories.

Comment: You probably also want `-mindepth 1`. `find . -maxdepth 1` returns `.` as one of its results.

Comment: Final q (I promise!): Using either find or mv ./*/* . how would I remove the empty directories when done? (I get an error if the directory is empty.) I'm assuming something like && rm '{}'

Comment: `&& rmdir -- "$dir"` before the `; done`. Again, you never want to use `{}` inside a `sh -c` or `bash -c` argument.

Comment: final final! Any way to suppress 'mv: rename ./test/* to ./*: No such file or directory' when a subdir is empty?

Comment: Making the script `bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; for dir; do files=( "$dir"/* ) && (( ${#files[@]} )) && mv -- "${files[@]}" . && rmdir "$dir"; done'` would have that effect. BTW, if your directories are arbitrarily large and you have GNU `xargs` and `mv`, better to make the `mv` piece `&& { printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | xargs -0 mv -t . --; } &&` to handle directories whose filenames add up to more than maximum command-line-argument-list length.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real need to use `find`. You can do it with a single `mv` to move the files and `rmdir` to remove the now-empty directories.

```
mv */* .
rmdir */
```

Comment: Yep. The question is, "How can I move all the files in subdirectories to the current level?" so I figured "no need to use find" deserved to be an answer.